# Magento 2 Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: magento2, facebook

I have installed extension for integrate facebook messenger chat. but giving " Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com" in console and also messenger live chat application not appear in front end.
what should I do for get this work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you updated to 2.3.5 version.

Just run this terminal command

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
```

More information here:
https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-disable-csp

[image]

Comment: thank you Joao. no luck yet.! i'm using M2.3

Comment: I think it has something to do with it, I-ve had the same issue with the Paypal frame and this solved it. Did you run the clean
/flush cache commands? Just updated the answer with the print of the error I was getting, please check if its similar to yours ;)

Comment: Question edited with snap shot

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file `etc/csp_whitelist.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="facebook-frame" type="host">*.facebook.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    <policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```